# Is it possible to permanently disable your shield in Clash of Clans?

Tags: clash-of-clans

For reasons I'd rather not get into, I want to permanently disable my shield, so unlimited people can attack me one after another. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not really possible, but if you wanted to just continuously disable it, launch an attack every time you get raided and they get 50% or your town hall. You could just go with a few barbs/archers and look for a farmer. There isn't a way to disable your shield.

Answer (score 2):

**2016 UPDATE**

While you cant technically disable your shield, you can simply dismiss it every time you have one by clicking on the "-" button on the upper-right part of the active shield icon. Just take note that removing all your shields (including village guard) will affect your total remaining online time.